# Multilingual blog, but only for some entries in a section, otherwise default to English

Tags: craft3, localization

My client has an English blog but wants a few of the posts to be available in German too.

How would I set things up so that the German version of the blog shows the German version of a post where available, but otherwise defaults to the English version?

(If “Propagate entries across all enabled sites?” is turned off, the German blog is effectively empty and they don't want to copy/paste all the old posts over from English to German if it can be avoided)

URLS are using a /en or /de prefix.